# How to add day variable in solidity smart-contract?

Tags: solidity

I want to use days counter in my smart-contract's code.
Is there any built-in constants or good practices to do that?
I tried to play with `now` and its comparison with timestamp numbers, but it seems pretty unobvious for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **time suffixes** after any integer.

In your case, you can use `1 days` which will be converted to an equivalent in **seconds**.

Take care about calendar calculations however, because in fact not every day has exactly the same amount of seconds because of *leap seconds*.

You can finf official Solidity documentation about it here:
http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/units-and-global-variables.html